# How can I safely lock my screen without password?

Tags: lock-screens

I have bought a new android phone (Samsung GT-S7710) with a new android system. It has a lot of useful features and lots of flaws caused by too hasty development.

One of these flaws is the lock screen. On my android version (4.1.2), the lock screen is unlocked by *sliding anywhere* to *any direction*. This often happens in my pocket and causes lot of problems (contacts getting deleted, random calls and so on).

[image: locked screen with finger at random position]

I still don't understand what was the programmer responsible for that thinking about. **It's just as ridiculous as having a keyboard phone that says "*Press any key to unlock!*".**

Of course, I could set up a password. The thing is, that my previous phone has returned to me, because there was no password and the man who found it could contact my relatives.

I actually see no reason to have a password in my phone anyway. I often borrow it to other people and password is just annoying.

So is there some lock-screen patch? Can I install some application that handles screen locking right? Can Android be updated to a fixed version? I **don't** want to root my phone though.

For those who don't get it from the above: **How can I lock my screen so that it won't unlock in my pocket easily?** I'm looking for a complete solution.

Oh and also, the top bar is not locked at all. It keeps turning on *Mobile data* and wasting my money (for me, mobile data is an expensive thing I want always turned off)

Comment: I'm confused at what's wrong here... This method is exactly how Android lock screens work, cross-device... My LG G3 is just the same - you swipe any direction.  What are you trying to accomplish with "locking"?  And as a second comment, the "top bar" you're referencing... Do you mean the notification bar?  It's not using data...  On all phones you can pull down the notification bar if there's no password on the lock screen.

Comment: Well, I'm complaining that it unlocks in my pocket all the time. That's total bullshit. It happens very often to me. I talked to other users about it and they all just use the password as a workaround.

Comment: Is my keyboard phone analogy so hard to understand?

Comment: Chill out, bro. I understand. The best you can do is download a lock screen replacement, and see if there's a method in any of those apps have a method you'd prefer... What is ideal for you? Do you have a method in mind that doesn't require a password?

Comment: To give you a proper solution, it'd be great if you could say exactly what you want..

Comment: I have no specific idea. I'm not the one who's paid to develop a practical mobile OS. I just want something that **doesn't take any actions while in my pocket** - like turning on mobile data and wasting my money (I have a very bad tarif).  I really wonder what you *don't understand* on my question.

Comment: Being rude isn't going to help at all, bud. I completely understand. However, to properly assist you in finding a lock screen replacement, we need to know **what you want**. For example, you could say "I like how the iPhone unlocks; requiring a swipe in a specific row." And on that topic: requests for a specific app are off topic here. Simply searching in Google Play for "lock screen" will return a plethora of lock screen replacements. You have to understand that this is how Android works - it's not a bug, and not improper programming. Therefore, there is no "patch" or "fixed version."

Comment: Two options: search for Go Locker and install that. Or turn your screen away from your leg while in your pocket.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your phone to NOT turn on in your pocket but still be able to have someone find your phone and identify it as yours, here's what I recommend.

1. Set your phone background message (the text that can display on your phone lock screen once enabled or edited) to your name and email address. Anyone who finds your phone can then contact you if they don't just want to steal it.
2. Enable a pass code, pattern lock, or password on your phone.

You will never be able to disable the emergency call option from your lock screen (unless you install a custom ROM), but this should help cut down on the butt dials and other issues.

Comment: So there is no safe lock without the password? Did Android developers at least explain, why they don't use the slide lock (which never failed me) any more?